# ジェネリクスに型を教えた状態のクラスを返したい

Tags: swift, ジェネリクス

とくに意味をなさないうえに冗長なコードですが、サンプルのために、下記のようなソースがあるとします。

```
class Hoge<T: Equatable, U: Equatable> {
    var x: T?
    var y: U?

    init() {
    }
}

typealias TT = String
typealias UU = Int

let hoge = Hoge<TT, UU>()
```

`T`には`String`。 `U`には`Int`を教えることができました(この`教える`にあたる専門用語を忘れてしまいました... 追記：`特殊化(specialization)`でした)。

これと同じことをするファクトリーのような関数を作りたいと考え下記のようにしましたがうまくいきません。うまい書き方はありますか？

```
func hogeFactory<TT: Equatable, UU: Equatable>() -> Hoge<TT, UU> {
    return Hoge<TT, UU>()
}

let h = hogeFactory<String, Int>()
```

> MyPlayground.playground:12:20: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
>   let h = hogeFactory()

Comment: まずは、質問文にあるようにクラス(いわゆるメタオブジェクト)を返したいのか、そのクラスのインスタンスを返したいのかよくわからないんですが?インスタンスを返したいのなら、ご掲載の関数(をちゃんとしたSwiftの文法に合わせれば)動くと思うんですが、それでは何が上手くないのかをもう少し例など交えて説明してもらえないでしょうか?

Comment: @OOPer インスタンスを返したいですが、正しい文法がわかっていないです。 `->` 以降の返却型の書き方が間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず`function`を`func`にするだけでコンパイルは通ると思うんですが?Swiftではジェネリック関数の呼び出し時にはジェネリックパラメータを明示的に指定できないので、呼び出しが面倒(普通にイニシャライザを使った方が簡単…)ではありますが。

Comment: @OOPer 失礼しました。凡ミスでした...

Comment: @OOPer うーん。とはいえまだエラーがでてしまいました。

Comment: 「呼び出し時にはジェネリックパラメータを明示的に指定できない」の部分ですね。ちょっとした回答を書いてみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントに書きましたが、Swiftではジェネリック関数を呼び出す時、ジェネリックパラメータ(この例でいう`TT`や`UU`に当てはめるための具体的な型)を明示的に指定することはできません。

```
func hogeFactory<TT: Equatable, UU: Equatable>() -> Hoge<TT, UU> {
    return Hoge<TT, UU>()
}

let h = hogeFactory<String, Int>() //<-これはエラーになる
```

もちろん型が決定できないのでは、別のエラーになります。では、どうやって指定するのかというと、型推論でそれが決定できるようにしてやらないといけません。

例えばこんな感じ。

```
let h: Hoge<String, Int> = hogeFactory()
```

ただ、これではせっかくファクトリーメソッドを作って、表から`Hoge`クラスの存在を隠したのに、あまり意味がない(普通にイニシャライザを使った方が簡単…)ように見えるので、こんな書き方もよくします。

```
func hogeFactory<TT: Equatable, UU: Equatable>(_:TT.Type, _:UU.Type) -> Hoge<TT, UU> {
    return Hoge<TT, UU>()
}

let hh = hogeFactory(String.self, Int.self)
```

後者の書き方(型推論ができるようにするためだけの型引数を持たせる)と言うのは、Swiftの標準ライブラリでもよく使われているのですが、何か動的に型が指定できるような気がしてくるという欠点があります。(Swiftの型推論はコンパイル時に働く、実行時に動的に働くのではない。)

その辺はまた実際の問題に遭遇した時に再度質問してもらった方がいいでしょう。