# Swift で型を変数に代入できるようになっているのは何に使うためですか？

Tags: swift

[realm swiftでindexPath.rowを使いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68507/19110) という質問を見て、Swift では型自体も第一級の値であり、変数に代入できるようになっていることを知りました。しかしアプリ用途かつ静的型付き言語である Swift で型を値として使えてどのように嬉しいのかが、すぐには分かりませんでした。

Swift で型を値として使うユースケースとして、どのようなものがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

例えばJSONDecoderは、JSONデータをマッピングする対象の型を引数としてとります。その型はなんでも良いわけではなく、Decodableプロトコルに準拠している必要があります。
下記のコードで、JSONデータがGroceryProductのインスタンスにマッピングされます。

```
struct GroceryProduct: Codable {
    var name: String
    var points: Int
    var description: String?
}

let json = """
{
    "name": "Durian",
    "points": 600,
    "description": "A fruit with a distinctive scent."
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let product = try decoder.decode(GroceryProduct.self, from: json)

print(product.name) // Prints "Durian"
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

これでJSONがDecodable準拠しているGroceryProductにマッピングされてGroceryProductのインスタンスが返ります。

Comment: なるほど、`decode` にデコード後の値が代入される先の変数への参照を渡すのではなく（例：Go）、型を渡して関数の戻り値として使えるようになっているのですね。ひとつのデザインとしてこう使えるようにするのを選択したのだと解釈しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[@kishikawa katsumi さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68952/9008) と言ってることは同じになってしまいますが、以前 [私が質問（ジェネリクスに型を教えた状態のクラスを返したい）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48617/%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E5%9E%8B%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%9F%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) して [回答してくださった内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/48620/9008) も役に立つと思います。

今回の質問において重要なところだけ引用します。

> Swiftではジェネリック関数を呼び出す時、ジェネリックパラメータ(この例でいうTTやUUに当てはめるための具体的な型)を明示的に指定することはできません。

> 書き方(型推論ができるようにするためだけの型引数を持たせる)と言うのは、Swiftの標準ライブラリでもよく使われているのですが、何か動的に型が指定できるような気がしてくるという欠点があります。(Swiftの型推論はコンパイル時に働く、実行時に動的に働くのではない。)

つまり`型自体`を`第一級の値`として、`ジェネリック関数`の引数に渡すことが標準ライブラリでもよく使われます。これは動的に型を指定できるような気がしてきますが、そうではなくコンパイル時に働いています。用途は型推論ができるようにするためです。